# Compile other external libraries (without CMakeLists.txt) with CMake

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

short -- Is it possible to build a external binary/library out of a project with CMake, when the binary/library only has a makefile given?

So you have your own project, a bunch of CMakeLists.txt in your src-tree and this external library with its source-files. Your sources depend on this library and some binaries/libraries want to link against it. How would one compile this external library if it has only a makefile or Visual Studio project file and no given CMakeLists.txt?
Is there a chance to call configure/make out of CMake? Or run an batch-compile with VS under Windows? Or anything else?

Thanks for your help with this one...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It sounds like you want CMake's external project. I have worked with it quite extensively when developing the Titan build system, and it provides a way of managing multiple out of source builds. You can include ExternalProject, and then something like the following would build the project:

```
ExternalProject_Add(Qt
   DOWNLOAD_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
   URL ${qt_file}
   UPDATE_COMMAND ""
   SOURCE_DIR ${qt_source}
   BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
   CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${qt_configure}
   BUILD_COMMAND ${qt_build}
   INSTALL_COMMAND "${qt_install}"
   )
```

There is an article about external projects in the [October 2009 issue of the source](http://web.archive.org/web/20100131222226/http://www.kitware.com/products/thesource/oct2009.html) too. Using external project you can call any make commands available on the host system, we build Qt using their supplied configure command on Windows, Mac and Linux.

Comment: I am glad it helped. There are several open source projects using this (such as Titan) that you could look at for examples.