# Cleanest way to depend on a make-based C library in my CMake C++ project

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile

I'm working on a C++ project (I am using `CMake`) and need to depend on a C library like this one (but uses `make`): https://github.com/RoaringBitmap/CRoaring

What's the cleanest way for me to integrate that library into my project?

One option is importing that code into my source tree, creating a CMakeLists.txt for that external dependency and using it as a CMake submodule. But I don't want to do that, since that project might evolve, and I just want that code as a git submodule dependency, and not actually committed into my repository.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compile other external libraries (without CMakeLists.txt) with CMake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489056/compile-other-external-libraries-without-cmakelists-txt-with-cmake)

Comment: Also duplicates [Building a library using autotools from cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971921/building-a-library-using-autotools-from-cmake)

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is use the build system of make within CMake if you `cd` into the sources of CRoaring and call external commands within CMakeLists.txt using the **execute_process** command:

[execute_process](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/execute_process.html)

With INSTALL_PREFIX you can indicate where to compile that library and cmake would use it then.

This also would mean, that the make compilation starts whenever you trigger configure though I imagine that you could control that a bit. If you want to avoid that **add_custom_command** could help you on this:

[add_custom_command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_command.html#command:add_custom_command)

For Commander Genius we have been using those when building the Windows version and using *icotool* so the executable gets an application icon embedded into the **exe**.

Another alternative would be using **ExternalProject** like indicated in the similar post by Tsyvarev:

[ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/ExternalProject.html)

Yet I'm not sure if that call is flexible enough for your needs. It has a lot of options though.

So the cleanest way to use CMake really depends on what you need to do for your project.